# SSRS Report - Dynamic table creation

Tags: dynamic, reporting-services

I am creating dynamic data set in order to build dynamic table on SSRS. But, the way I am creating this dataset, I can only create two dynamic columns. Could you please help me to build more dynamic columns. Please let me know if I can do this with the help of matrix if table is not possible.

My code for dynamic dataset is:

```
="select  " & IIF(InStr(Parameters!ReferenceName.Value,"common")>0, "DayOfWeek", "Code") & " AS Column1, " 
    & IIF(InStr(Parameters!ReferenceName.Value,"View")  >01, "Name","MonthName") &   " AS Column2 "
    & " from "  & Parameters!ReferenceName.Value
```

Comment: Added some formatting to the question

Comment: the number of columns, is always going to be same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish here.

An easier way may be to create a UNION of all your tables with an extra column with the type and filter it later by **TableType** = Parameters!ReferenceName.Value.

```
SELECT DayOfWeek AS Column1, MonthName AS Column2, 'Common' as TableType
FROM common_TABLE
UNION 
SELECT Code AS Column1, Name AS Column2, 'View' as TableType
FROM view_TABLE
```

Comment: I have created dynamic dataset, but I am not able to go forward with the parameterName comparison in the dataset.

Comment: To filter your dataset or table, use an expression similar to what you were using before  **=IIF(InStr(Parameters!ReferenceName.Value, FIELDS!TableType.Value)  > 0, 1, 0)** and change the **Type** to INTEGER, the operator to **0** and the Value to **1**.  Is your parameter multi-value? If it is, you'll need to convert it with SPLIT first.